# Populate datatable with custom nested response

Tags: javascript, json, datatable, datatables

I am very new to data tables. And I need to populate data table with custom response other than default data table response.

please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h146fk9a/). It is working fine with simple response , BUT now I need to populate data table with more complex response. Below is my code.

**HTML**

```
<table id="table" class="display responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead style="background-color:#303641;color:#fff;">
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>number</th>
            <th>maxDate</th>
            <th>minDate</th>
            <th>number2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var result = '{"msg":"success","code":"200","status":null,"data":[{"id":3663101,"lstImeis":[{"number":"18966399926043","maxDate":"2017-08-24 22:08:58.0","minDate":"2017-08-24 22:08:58.0"},{"number":"22418344742097","maxDate":"2017-08-24 18:08:56.0","minDate":"2017-08-24 18:08:56.0"}],"number2":789},{"id":3665337,"lstImeis":[{"number":"32756451080799","maxDate":"2017-08-24 21:09:38.0","minDate":"2017-08-24 21:09:38.0"},{"number":"42540009239622","maxDate":"2017-08-24 16:35:08.0","minDate":"2017-08-24 16:35:08.0"}],"number2":456}],"draw":0,"limit":0,"recordsFiltered":0,"recordsTotal":0}';

    var json = JSON.parse(result);
    var tableData = json.data;

    $('#table').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "aaData": tableData,
        "aoColumns": [{
            "mData": "id"
        }, {
            "mData": "number"
        }, {
            "mData": "maxDate"
        }, {
            "mData": "minDate"
        }, {
            "mData": "number2"
        }]
    });


});
```

With this `JSON` response, I am unable to populate the required data in data table. I have created this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u0379d04/) as well.

I have studied this [link](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/deep.html) as well, but I dopnt understand how to manage nested response in data table.

Any idea, how to populate this data into data table.  ? OR any good reference ?

Comment: The example you are following is related to DataTable version `1.10` but you are using legacy version of DataTable.

Comment: please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u0379d04/2/) it shows the `id` and `number2` values but not other values ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so after some help from google, I manage to show the correct response, I used the follwoiung java script code to populate my data into data table.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var result = '{"msg":"success","code":"200","status":null,"data":[{"id":3663101,"lstImeis":[{"number":"18966399926043","maxDate":"2017-08-24 22:08:58.0","minDate":"2017-08-24 22:08:58.0"},{"number":"22418344742097","maxDate":"2017-08-24 18:08:56.0","minDate":"2017-08-24 18:08:56.0"}],"number2":789},{"id":3665337,"lstImeis":[{"number":"32756451080799","maxDate":"2017-08-24 21:09:38.0","minDate":"2017-08-24 21:09:38.0"},{"number":"42540009239622","maxDate":"2017-08-24 16:35:08.0","minDate":"2017-08-24 16:35:08.0"}],"number2":456}],"draw":0,"limit":0,"recordsFiltered":0,"recordsTotal":0}';

  var json = JSON.parse(result);
  var tableData = json.data;

  $('#table').DataTable({
                "processing": true,
            "serverSide": false,
            "bFilter": false,
            "aaData": tableData,
                "aoColumns": [
                        { "mData": "id" },
                        { "mData": "lstImeis.0.number" },
                        { "mData": "lstImeis.0.maxDate" },
                        { "mData": "lstImeis.0.minDate" },
                        { "mData": "number2" }
                ],

            });


});
```

I hope it will help some one else !!